# How to disable certain console warnings in Qt

Tags: qt, warnings

On some paint events, Qt outputs several warnings in the console: "QPainter::begin: Painter already active"

I would like to disable this particular warning because it clutters the Output window and I'm not planning to fix it. How can I do that?

Comment: That warnings tells you that your code is obviously doing wrong things.

Comment: Try with a release build. Also calling begin(), usually is not necessary at all.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I removed the only one call I had to begin() in my code and that stopped all the warnings. The reason I wasn't planning to fix it is that it indeed seemed like the code was doing something unnecessary but not harmful. Well, now that the warning is fixed, that's even better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do it is to remove it from the Qt sources and recompile them. But it would be much easier and reliable to just fix the cause.

P. S. Actually, as noted in the other answer, it is possible to install an msg handler and filter out that particular message by calling strcmp(), but that's both ugly and not very reliable - if the message is altered in any future version, it will start appearing again.

Answer (score 12):

You can suppress any Qt message by installing your own message handlers with [`qInstallMessageHandler`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler). The specific message you mentioned is a [`qWarning`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qWarning) message.

Comment: Both these answers are partly correct and partly wrong. A. You can handle the warnings yourself by installing a handler, but B. You should just fix the problem causing the warning.

Comment: There are circumstances where some warnings are better suppressed; for instance, if you try to load a TIFF file with certain tags missing, Qt will load it just fine, but complain to the console. It'd be better if it didn't do that, and just quietly loaded the image, since it is able to do that.