# hide all QT application warning which are printed on terminal?

Tags: windows, qt, qt4, warnings

when i run a qt application i get warning messages.

```
$ ./TestLauncher
QSystemTrayIcon::setVisible: No Icon set
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_Save_clicked()
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_CancelButton_clicked()
...
```

I just want to hide all the warnings which are printed on terminal when application is running

Comment: Why do you need to hide them (warnings) instead of fixing your code? They look pretty useful.

Comment: actually my original application runs fine, i just want to try some modifications. it can be fixed but it will take some time also i dont want to break anything and fix that instead of testing new case

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable certain console warnings in Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791838/how-to-disable-certain-console-warnings-in-qt)

Comment: Well, that suggested duplicate does not actually have a very good answer, just a general principle of installing message handler. It is also a more specific question of how to hide *some* warnings.

Comment: The solution (and links to more info and [a good example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler)) is actually said at [docs for `qWarning`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qWarning): install message handler and do not print the warning messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `QT_NO_WARNING_OUTPUT` macro. See [Qt Debug Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/debug.html)

Comment: Does this really work with warnings from the Qt libs? I mean, does it work without recompiling the whole Qt?

Comment: You don't need to recompile Qt

Comment: better way is to add following in .pro file   "DEFINES    += QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT QT_NO_WARNING_OUTPUT "

Answer (score 0):

well i didnt find any QT function so i have redirected output of the application but now the drawback is that it will hide non QT warnings to.

```
freopen( "/dev/null", "w", stdin );
freopen( "/dev/null", "w", stdout );
freopen( "/dev/null", "w", stderr );
```